# Counting neighboring cells for Conway's Game of Life in C++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to write a count neighbor method for Conway's game of life. If a dead cell is neighbored by 2 or 3 living cells, it should come alive. However, my code is not correctly counting all the neighbors. If i give the input coordinates (10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12) which would produce

```
   ***
```

the program will print the next generation as

```
    *
    *
```

with coordinates at (10, 11) and (11, 11). However, there should also be a point at (9,11). I know that the problem occurs in this function and that for point (9,11) the function is not counting 3 neighbors.

```
int Life::neighbor_count (int row, int col)
{
  int i, j;
  int count=0;
  for(i=row-1; i<row+1; i++){
    for (j=col-1; j<=col+1; j++){
      count +=grid[i][j];//increase the count is neighbor is alive
    }
  }
  count -=grid [row][col];//reduce count, since cell is not its own neighbor
  return count;
}
```

Comment: how do you update the grid? If i remember right, you have to have two grids in memory, the old one and the updated one so that you are counting the old neighbors and not the already updated ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexD pointed out, `i<row+1` should be `i<=row+1` which would explain your answer.